# Google chrome closes immediately after being launched with selenium after 2s it close

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

i use windows 8.1 and python 3.12.0 and selenuim 4.14.0
and this is my code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
chrome_driver_path = 'C:\chromedriver.exe'

service = Service(chrome_driver_path)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)

driver.get('https://www.hlth.com/2023event/sponsors')
```

and this is the error i get on the terminal

```
D:\vscode\selenium\seleinum.py:6: SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence '\c'
  chrome_driver_path = 'C:\chromedriver.exe'

DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:51038/devtools/browser/d6492c24-7885-42f4-a96d-969315c4d860
[4208:4140:1025/150705.314:ERROR:network_service_instance_impl.cc(539)] Network service crashed, restarting service.

[4208:4140:1025/150716.345:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(215)] [15:07:16.344] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1046 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: A device attached to the system is not functioning. (0x1F)
```

i am trying to scrap this web site with help of selenium on python but the page open but  after 2s close

Answer (score 0):

Use `'C:\\chromedriver.exe'`, or \c will be taken for an escape sequence